# How I know the url when wants to make a json request?

Tags: javascript, json, url, jsonp

Hej,

Seems a bit stupid to ask but really want to know. For example, I want to get the information under the title "Identification" in the following webpage,"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag#Identification" then I could use script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", null, function(wiki) {
      <!-- code -->
});
</script>
```

but in this case, what's the url should be?

Comment: Screen scraping does'nt work that way, luckily! You should be using a serverside language, and it's a lot more involved than just sending a random ajax request.

Comment: see if you can get the url within the success method with `this.url`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag does not return JSON, and the [hash fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) is absolutely irrelevant for a web request. However, for the English wikipedia there is an API (which also works cross-domain) at http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Comment: @Bergi Great, that's what I mean, and can you tell me how can I get a workable url(server side url) such as en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php from the original url(customer side url) some like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page ? Is there anyway or rules to get it?(add .php in the end? I know it's not right but just for example)

Comment: @trivial: No, you need to know that. I mean, it is not supported by every website, only those that use the MediaWiki software and have the API enabled.